Raised ridges with shirt mesh
I'm in the game making industry and I have been working on a skin for a character.The raised sewing always happens for some reason and originally, I had found an answer to this problem in the physics tabm but i forgot where it where it was so i spent over 3-6 weeks looking for it. (also this is with welding on).

also for reference this is the tutorial I'm following.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-f5RgG_Yywg


these are my modifiers if there is anything else you need pls let me know.
also here is blend file.

pls provide blend file because we have no idea what your settings are and how you geometry looks like.

will do gimme a sec

didn't let me but i can give you screen shots

just open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

how long is it suposed to take?

never mind got it

if you hide your solidify modifier and turn on "face orientation" you will see that you have a face orientation problem:

if you fix that, it works.
so select these vertices:

use mesh normals > flip

result:

with a weld modifier in between you can get even smoother results:


Cool.... but aren't the ridges still there in the result?

@RobinBetts: i think a weld modifier can handle that ;)

sort of what I was guessing at.... below Cloth,above Solidify. but I haven't checked

ty i got it to mostly do it thanks

i did try to but it said that i wasn't a high enough level i'll try again
